# c++ compilng failed

Tags: compiling, c++

I have tried to build and run c++ files but it failes every time I try.
here is the code when I compile it in the terminal

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:508,
             from /usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/iostream:38,
             from a.cpp:2:
`/usr/include/features.h:424:12: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory


`/usr/include/features.h:424:12: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
```

#  include 
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.'

Comment: You appear to be using a non-standard toolchain in a non-standard location (`/usr/local`). Where did you get it and how did you install it? Why are you not using one of the versions of `g++` provided by the Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You need g++-multilb package

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Comment: this is the result  : `usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @Yobar try to install gcc-multilib too

Comment: the same error message  was generated

Comment: sudo apt-get install libc-dev

Comment: Or try libc6-dev